# Nginx rewrite to specific part of requested uri

Tags: nginx, rewrite, query, request

I am quite new to nginx rewrite concept and I can't figure out how to rewrite the requested_uri to a specific Uri. I am trying to make rewrites to specific js files.

For example, I have this `requested_uri: http://test.example.com/mf/test/index.js?review=abc`
I want to rewrite it only to `/index.js`

I am using my own specific domain for that. I want to rewrite everything to */index.js* so that I can get a js file as a response.

I am really struggling to find out how it works. Can anyone help me do this, please?

Comment: Are you trying to drop the query string or keep it in the request?

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to the question so that your configuration is visible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641603/remove-parameters-within-nginx-rewrite

Comment: @Paul I am trying to drop the query string.

Comment: @gapsf I am also trying to remove the part before index.js except from the query string.

Comment: I think something like `location ^~ /mv/test/index.js { rewrite ^/index.js$ $scheme://test.example.com/index.js?; }` or optionally add `permanent;` parameter on the end if you want to have nginx respond with 301 Moved Permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
location ^~ /mv/test/index.js {
    rewrite ^/index.js$ $scheme://test.example.com/index.js?;
}
```

Add `permanent` if you want it to be a 301 Moved Permanently:

```
location ^~ /mv/test/index.js {
    rewrite ^/index.js$ $scheme://test.example.com/index.js? permanent;
}
```

Comment: I want to remove also the part $scheme://test.example.com/. After the rewrite the link should be /index.js only without anything else. I proxy it to a microservice in order to get back a JS file.

Comment: Please post at least the entire server block that `rewrite` is in and all other relevant configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite to last part

```
rewrite ^.*\/(.+)\?.*$/ $1
```